# Override XMLHttpRequest and emulate response

Tags: javascript, cordova, xmlhttprequest, python-requests, phonegap

Would it be possible to override XMLHttpRequest and emulate response from a callback ?

Something like :

```js
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
        var url = arguments[1];
        if (url === 'someUrl' && isOnline === false){
          //Return a fake reponse to the request...
        }
        ...
    }
```

It would be realy nice to do this in my phonegap app, so if the user is offline I could retrieve the response from my local sqlite db.

Comment: have you tried at all? returning a value using `open` doesn't *emulate* how XMLHttpRequest actually works, so you'd need to rethink the whole idea - but, rather than fiddling with the innards of XHR, why not conditionally use XHR - `if (url === 'someUrl' && isOnline === false){ fake the response } else { use XHR }`

Comment: The XHR requests are made by a JS framework, thats why I would like to emulate a success or a error response..

Comment: Instead of getting your hands messy with 'prototype'  ..i will suggest using the network plugin to detect if the device is offline or not ...and use an IF statement to choose between requesting data from the internet or running a function to handle the request locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use mockjax plugin.